# Windows Cmd Delete Item from HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry

I added an item to startup using the command

```
REG ADD HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V "OMG" /t REG_SZ /F /D "C:\WGET\wget.exe"
```

And after I tryed to delete it with the command :

```
REG DELETE "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "OMG" /f
```

But with no succes. I searched for this type of question but with no result. I will realy apreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
rem    ↓↓ missing " double quote
REG ADD HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V "OMG" /t REG_SZ /F /D "C:\WGET\wget.exe"
rem    ↑↑ missing " double quote
```

Missing `"` double quote causes misinterpreting keys as follows:

```
==> REG ADD HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V "OMG" /t REG_SZ /F /D "C:\WGET\wget.exe"
The operation completed successfully.

==> reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" /S | findstr /C:"CurrentVersion\Run " 2>NUL
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /V OMG /t REG_SZ /F /D C:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /V OMG /t REG_SZ /F /D C:\WGET
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /V OMG /t REG_SZ /F /D C:\WGET\wget.exe

==>
```

Add missing `"` double quote as follows:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V "OMG" /t REG_SZ /F /D "C:\WGET\wget.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, You missed the 'Double Quotes' After **REG ADD**. But, in this method you are choosing, You need to run the script as an 'Admin'. While, Giving a Batch file **Admin Access** Can never be a good idea.

So, You can try the alternative of, Copying the Shortcut (the file to Execute at startup) to the path -> ***"%Userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"*** - No Admin Needed. :)